# Inline 100% Width Div Leaves Gap

Tags: html, email, width, inline

I am making an email signature with a 100% width div. However, whilst using inline styling, there are gaps either side of the div. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fJ78F/ and the code:

```
<div style='width:100%;background:red;margin:0;padding:0;'>
<p> test </p>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Add `margin:0` to the `<body>`'s style.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Will mark as answer when it lets me. Thank you!